# list files by length file name order, after alphabetic

Tags: bash, shell

I have these files:

```
-rw-rw-r-- 1 root     boincadm 21170 Jul 19 16:42 wilson_job_79
-rw-rw-r-- 1 root     boincadm 18170 Jul 19 16:42 wilson_job_8
-rw-rw-r-- 1 root     boincadm 21288 Jul 19 16:42 wilson_job_80
-rw-rw-r-- 1 root     boincadm 21180 Jul 19 16:38 wilson_job_81
-rw-rw-r-- 1 root     boincadm 21156 Jul 19 16:36 wilson_job_82
-rw-rw-r-- 1 root     boincadm 21414 Jul 19 16:26 wilson_job_85
-rw-rw-r-- 1 root     boincadm 21194 Jul 19 16:29 wilson_job_86
-rw-rw-r-- 1 root     boincadm 21148 Jul 19 16:29 wilson_job_87
-rw-rw-r-- 1 root     boincadm 21176 Jul 19 16:27 wilson_job_88
-rw-rw-r-- 1 root     boincadm 21240 Jul 19 16:42 wilson_job_89
-rw-rw-r-- 1 root     boincadm 18136 Jul 19 16:26 wilson_job_9
-rw-rw-r-- 1 root     boincadm 21260 Jul 19 16:38 wilson_job_90
-rw-rw-r-- 1 root     boincadm 21174 Jul 19 16:34 wilson_job_91
```

and when I list I want the answer in order by number:

```
-rw-rw-r-- 1 root     boincadm 18170 Jul 19 16:42 wilson_job_8
-rw-rw-r-- 1 root     boincadm 18136 Jul 19 16:26 wilson_job_9
-rw-rw-r-- 1 root     boincadm 21170 Jul 19 16:42 wilson_job_79
-rw-rw-r-- 1 root     boincadm 21288 Jul 19 16:42 wilson_job_80
-rw-rw-r-- 1 root     boincadm 21180 Jul 19 16:38 wilson_job_81
-rw-rw-r-- 1 root     boincadm 21156 Jul 19 16:36 wilson_job_82
-rw-rw-r-- 1 root     boincadm 21414 Jul 19 16:26 wilson_job_85
-rw-rw-r-- 1 root     boincadm 21194 Jul 19 16:29 wilson_job_86
-rw-rw-r-- 1 root     boincadm 21148 Jul 19 16:29 wilson_job_87
-rw-rw-r-- 1 root     boincadm 21176 Jul 19 16:27 wilson_job_88
-rw-rw-r-- 1 root     boincadm 21240 Jul 19 16:42 wilson_job_89
-rw-rw-r-- 1 root     boincadm 21260 Jul 19 16:38 wilson_job_90
-rw-rw-r-- 1 root     boincadm 21174 Jul 19 16:34 wilson_job_91
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take advantage of the fact that the underscore character "_" only appears in your file name in the output of `ls -l`:

```
ls -l | sort -t_ -k1,2 -k3n
```

Answer (score 3):

If you have GNU tools, let `ls` handle it: `ls -vl`

http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/Details-about-version-sort.html

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

`ls | sort -V | xargs -i ls -ld {}`

This runs ls (which just outputs a list of filenames), pipes it through sort -V (which does a "version number" sort), and then sends each line to ls -ld (which outputs details for each file).

Answer (score 1):

Using sed, assuming only digits in filename are in the sort field:

```
ls | sed 's/[^0-9]*\([0-9]*\)*/\1 &/' | sort -n -k1 | cut -d' ' -f2
```

- The `sed` command here creates a new column with just the file
  number, for example for file23 it will print out "23 file23".
- `sort` command numerically  (`-n`) sorts by the first field (or key,
  `-k1`)
- `cut` command removes the first field and only prints the second
  field (`-f2`). For example, it will print `file23` from the input `23
  file23`.

Comment: Nice! It worked! what is the sed command? and the parameters -k1 -f2?

Answer (score 0):

Use version sort on the 9th field:

```
ls -l | sort -k9V
```

Comment: If the filenames have spaces, you can't count on using the 9th field.

Comment: Of course, it shouldn't be restricted to only the 9th field. I'll fix it.

Comment: @Luca: yes, but that omits the long-listing information the OP wanted.

Comment: @Thor: Thanks, I did not realize that part. BTW, in Os X sort does not have the -V option. Any alternatives?

Comment: @Luca: Then either _perreal's_ or _chepner's_ answers should work.